# How to use reserved keywords as column names

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have used name of my row named 'group' and I want to take some info from it but it is saying that

> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "group" LINE 1:
> SELECT * FROM markapp_alllessons WHERE group='31м'

This is my code.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM markapp_alllessons WHERE group='31м'")
ls_check = cur.fetchone()
```

**I wrote big amount of code on Django and there were not any problems, but now I need to take some info from dB without Django. How can I use the variable 'group'?**

Comment: `group` is clearly a SQL keyword.  Use a different name.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 1):

Just double quote it

```
SELECT * FROM markapp_alllessons WHERE "group"='31м'
```

But it is not a good practice to use reserved names.

Comment: You should triple quote the SQL query. Otherwise this doesn't work.

Comment: Yikes, my bad, I missed that it's cursor. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM markapp_alllessons WHERE "group"='31м'""")
```